# Angular2 - How does my module import and use another module?

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

My component, ListingComponent, uses a component called MemberCountryFilter.   I have this module and everything is working.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [ListingComponent, MemberCountryFilter],
    exports: [ListingComponent,MemberCountryFilter,],
    providers: []

})
export class ListingComponent { }
```

I have realized that another module will soon need the MemberCountryFilter component so I refactored.  I created this module, for the MemberCountryFilter component, and I want to import it into other modules.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [MemberCountryFilter],
    exports: [MemberCountryFilter],
    providers: []
})
export class FilterModule { }
```

I changed my original module to this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FilterModule],
    declarations: [ListingComponent],
    exports: [ListingComponent, FilterModule,],
    providers: []

})
export class ListingComponent { }
```

After doing this I get vague template parse errors like this:

> zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. ("]*ngFor="let smc of selectedMemberCountries">

It appears that ListingComponent does not know what MemberCountryFilter is.  Obviously there is something I don't understand about modules.  I have read the documentation and I think I am doing it correctly.

The export in FilterModule should make MemberCountryFilter available.  Then I import it in ListingSharedModule, and export it which should make it available to ListingComponent.

For a basic overview, I had MemberCountryFilter as a declaration (with export) and it worked.  I moved it into another module, then import and export that module but it does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: NgFor directive belongs to CommonModule that is imported from BrowserModule, maybe you should import BrowserModule on ListingSharedModule

Comment: CommonModule at the api reference https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CommonModule-class.html

Comment: I have CommonModule as an import.  I left them out for brevity.  I'll update the post.   Basically, it was working, then I removed MemberCountryFilter and replaced it with that FilterModule and it stopped working.  I didn't want to clutter the post with a lot of unrelated items.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error before, what happen to me was I missed `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/core'` in my `*.module.ts` file,
for your `FilterModule`, please try this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [MemberCountryFilter],
    exports: [MemberCountryFilter],
    providers: []
})
export class FilterModule { }
```

Comment: That's the answer.  I thought common module just needed to be loaded bu the time it was used, and it was.  But now I know it needs to be loaded in the module where it's used.